# How to prevent TypeScript/Vue from renaming classes with underscore on build?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, web-component, vue-cli

I have a fairly simple class inside my web-component:

```
import {WorkItem} from '@/model/WorkItem'
   
const Data = 'data'

class ReqItem extends WorkItem {
  constructor(
    id: string,
    name: string,
  ) {
    super(id, name, Data)
  }
}

export {Data, ReqItem}
```

The problem is when TypeScript/Vue builds the entire thing into a web-component (command: `vue-cli-service build --target wc --name x`) it renames this class to `Filename_Classname`, which in this case is `ReqItem_ReqItem` like so:

```
// CONCATENATED MODULE: ./src/model/ReqItem.ts

const Data = 'data'

class ReqItem_ReqItem extends WorkItem {
  constructor(id, name) {
    super(id, name, Data);
  }

}
```

Why does this happen and how can it be prevented? As soon as I remove the `extends` the problem vanishes.

**Edit:** It keeps getting weirder: When I put the class and the class it extends (`ReqItem` and `WorkItem`) into one file the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the `index.ts` which looked like this:

```
.
.
export {WorkItem} from './WorkItem'
export {ReqItem} from './ReqItem'
.
.
```

changing it to

```
.
.
export * from './WorkItem'
export * from './ReqItem'
.
.
```

as described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#re-exports) resolved the issue.